# how to make minified and readable css file in sublime text?

Tags: css, html, sublimetext

how do I not just minify my css file but also get it readable in Sublime Text like this...

```
.element-1 { color:black; font-size:16px; display:block}
.element-2 { color:green; font-size:12px; display:inline}
.element-3 { color:brown; font-size:20px; display:flex}
```

rather than minify it into single line of code which is hard-to-read like this...

```
.element-1{color:black;font-size:16px;display:block}.element-2{color:green;font-size:12px;display:inline}.element-3{color:brown;font-size:20px;display:flex}
```

I have tried searching for sublime text plug-ins that can deal with this task, but haven't found such plugin like that yet. All of plugins that I found(such as [Minify](https://github.com/tssajo/Minify) and [sublime-html5-minifier](https://github.com/geekpradd/sublime-html5-minifier)) compress it into single line. How do I get such minified and easy-to-read CSS result ? Thanks in advance :)

PS. sorry for that as I'm not native English speaker, I have only a few keywords in my head to search for particular plugins. That's why I ask such stupid question like this.

Comment: You would just be stripping out the whitespace characters. I'm not sure if Sublime Text has regex find and replace functionality, but if it does you could replace something like `[\s\r\n]` with nothing.

Comment: Thank you @Eraph for your comment. Yes!!! it has regex find. That is a good idea !!! I will try it out.

Comment: I tested it, and it works!! thanks for your great idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Format

This one should do the trick.

Example.

```
html,body{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
.clearfix:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both;}
```

You can also look at the others examples in the link above.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you. that is what I am looking for but have no idea how to search it. Thank you again Paran0a.